Concise way to convert list of int to list of enum
I need to convert a list of int values to list of enum values and vice versa. I can create a simple conversion method but wanted to see if there's a more concise way to handle this.
Here's what my enum values look like:
public enum AutoShipOption
{
   Monthly = 2,
   Weekly = 1,
   Yearly = 3,
   Undefined = 0
}

And in my class that I use to define a store item, I get a List<int> that I need to convert to List<AutoShipOption>. As I said, it's easy to create a simple method that handles this that looks like this:
public List<AutoShipOption> AutoShipOptionsMapper(List<int> values)
{
   var options = new List<AutoShipOption>();

   if(values == null || values.Count == 0)
      return options;

   foreach(var item in values)
      if(item > 0)
         options.Add((AutoShipOption)item);

   return options;
}

Is there a more concise way to handle this conversion?

Is it possible for the List to contain invalid enum values?

I need to convert a list of int values to list of enum values and vice versa, I only see trying to convert an list of int to a list of enum, are you needing a list of enum to a list of int as well?

@Steve.  Concise?  What are the semantics of AutoShipOptionsMapper?  if(item > 0) I often criticize this pattern coding interviews because if your input contains values that don't make sense - what does that mean?  You probably want an error, as opposed to ignoring trash.  (It's not mapping, it's filtering - beware your name)  Also, sometimes you get the same (empty) list and sometimes you get a new list.  Is it safe to add to the list (no) so why not return an array?  Be aware that it's legal, from a language standpoint, for the enum AutoShipOption to hold any int value.

This is all it takes via LINQ:
      public static List<AutoShipOption> AutoShipOptionsMapper(List<int> values)
        {
            if (values == null)
                return new List<AutoShipOption>();

            return values
                .Where(item => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(AutoShipOption), item))
                .Select(item => (AutoShipOption)item)
                .ToList();
        }

Refer the full code below:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace EnumConversion
{
    public enum AutoShipOption
    {
        Monthly = 2,
        Weekly = 1,
        Yearly = 3,
        Undefined = 0
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> intValues = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, -1 };
            List<AutoShipOption> enumValues = AutoShipOptionsMapper(intValues);
            Console.WriteLine("AutoShipOptions values:");
            foreach (var option in enumValues)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(option);
            }
        }

        public static List<AutoShipOption> AutoShipOptionsMapper(List<int> values)
        {
            if (values == null)
                return new List<AutoShipOption>();

            return values
                .Where(item => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(AutoShipOption), item))
                .Select(item => (AutoShipOption)item)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}


Refer to the working .netfiddle here


You can use LINQ Cast as below:
var ints = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
var enums = ints
    .Where(x => Enum.IsDefined<AutoShipOption>(x))
    .Cast<AutoShipOption>()
    .ToList();

Such method you can encapsulate in some generic extension methods for IEnumerable and List:
public static class EnumEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static List<T> SafeListCast<T>(this List<T> list)
        where T : struct, Enum
    {
        return list.SafeCast().ToList();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> SafeCast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        where T : struct, Enum
    {
        return enumerable
            .Where(Enum.IsDefined)
            .Cast<T>();
    }
}

Then the example would be simplified:
var ints = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
var enums = ints.SafeListCast<AutoShipOption>();


That converts to IEnumerable<AutoShipOption> not to List<AutoShipOption>.  You would need to write ints.Cast<AutoShipOption>().ToList()

What happens when a value doesnt exist for an enum in this solution? See SELA answer below for something less error prone.

@Trevor I followed "error-prone" approach OPs applied, it suggested that its safe. I focused on simplicity, which was main focus. Nevertheless, corrected that.
